# Understanding Kivy Free Clock

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a metronome with kivy, i got my +, -, start button and a label which refers to the tempo.

When i click start button i run:

```
self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.job, self.bpm)
```

to start my timer however there are some issues.

As i click the button the timer starts with tiny noticable delay as kivy.Clock relies on frames from what i read and i should be using "Free Clock" instead but i couldn't make it work and didn't understand what i should be doing.

Second issue is when i schedule a timer it starts and keeps on going with its initial interval value, changing bpm won't change the current timer's interval until i cancel and restart it.

I would appreciate your ideas to find a way around this. My Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


Window.size = 320, 568
kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class mainWindow(FloatLayout):
    tempo = 60
    bpm = 60/tempo
    labelTempo = StringProperty(str(tempo))
    interval = False

    def startTimer(self, state):
        if state == "startMtr" and self.interval == False:
            self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.job, self.bpm)

        elif state == "stop":
            self.event.cancel()

    def button(self, btn):
        if btn == "+":
            self.tempo += 1
            self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
            self.bpm = 60 / self.tempo

        if btn == "-":
            self.tempo -= 1
            self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
            self.bpm = 60 / self.tempo

        if btn == "start":
            self.startTimer("startMtr")
            print("started")

        if btn == "stop":
            self.startTimer("stop")
            print("stopped")
    abc = 0
    def job(self, dt):
        self.abc += 1
        print(self.abc)
        print(App.get_running_app().root.bpm)
        print(App.get_running_app().root.tempo)


class crApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crApp().run()
```

Kv file:

```
<mainWindow>:

    FloatLayout:
        minus: minus
        start: start
        plus: plus

        Button:
            id: minus
            text: "-"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "top": 0.4}
            on_release:
                root.button("-")

        ToggleButton:
            id: start
            text: "start"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.4}
            on_press:
                root.button("start") if start.state == "down" else root.button("stop")

        Button:
            id: plus
            text: "+"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "top": 0.4}
            on_release:
                root.button("+")

        Label:
            id: tempo
            text: root.labelTempo
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) docs:

> The default clock suffers from the quantization problem, as frames occur only on intervals and any scheduled timeouts will not be able to occur during an interval.

So to get around that, use the "free clock" by

1. Selecting a clock mode using the config:

```py
# set config options before other imports
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'free_all')
```

Where there are four options:

> When kivy_clock is `default`, the normal clock, ClockBase, which limits
> callbacks to the maxfps quantization - is used.
>
> When kivy_clock is `interrupt`, a interruptible clock,
> ClockBaseInterrupt, which doesn’t limit any callbacks to the maxfps -
> is used. Callbacks will be executed at any time.
>
> When kivy_clock is `free_all`, a interruptible clock,
> ClockBaseFreeInterruptAll, which doesn’t limit any callbacks to the
> maxfps in the presence of free events, but in their absence it limits
> events to the fps quantization interval - is used.
>
> When kivy_clock is `free_only`, a interruptible clock,
> ClockBaseFreeInterruptAll, which treats free and normal events
> independently; normal events are fps limited while free events are not
> is used.

2. call the `_free` method version:

```py
Clock.schedule_interval_free(self.job, self.bpm)
```